# Alert popup and confirm disable the e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have textboxes in html table, and I want to bind the enter event with jQuery like this

```
$(function () 
$('#MainPage_resultatTable td.resultat input:text')
.bind('keydown',function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          confirm('are-you ok ?');  /* or alert*/
      }
  });
  });
```

The `e.preventDefault()` doesn't work. The postback is achieved
When I remove the "confirm" line the `e.preventDefault()` do the job.

Any suggestion for keeping the confim popup without postback would be appreciated.

Note : I tried it with `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`. Same result.

Comment: Firstly, you should use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode` but i don't think it would be an issue here. Secondly, can you replicate issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: the problem is not the e.keyCode because without confim line it's work

Comment: Maybe the components confirm and alert ignore the command `e.preventDefault()` because the have thier own keyboard control.

Comment: @MediSoft Ya that was a suggestion on how you should do it. Regarding issue, i guess use `keypress` instead of `keydown`

Comment: It's ok, it's work with keypress. thanks for A. Wolff